# Abaqus Python 'Getclosest' command

Tags: python-2.7, abaqus

I'm using the getclosest command to find a vertex.

```
ForceVertex1 = hatInstance.vertices.getClosest(coordinates=((x,y,z,))
```

This is a dictionary object with Key 0 and two values (hatInstance.vertices[1] and the coordinates of the vertex) The specific output:

```
{0: (mdb.models['EXP-100'].rootAssembly.instances['hatInstance-100'].vertices[1], (62.5242172081597, 101.192447407436, 325.0))}
```

Whenever I try to create a set, the vertex isn't accepted

```
mainAssembly.Set(vertices=ForceVertex1[0][0],name='LoadSet1')
```

I also tried a different way:

```
tolerance = 1.0e-3

        vertex = []
        for vertex in hatInstance.vertices:
           x = vertex.pointOn[0][0]
           print x
           y = vertex.pointOn[0][1]
           print y
           z = vertex.pointOn[0][2]
           print z
           break
           if (abs(x-xTarget)) < tolerance and abs(y-yTarget) < tolerance and abs(z-zTarget) < tolerance):
             vertex.append(hatInstance.vertices[vertex.index:vertex.index+1])
```

xTarget etc being my coordinates, despite this I still don't get a vertex object

Answer (score 3):

For those struggeling with this, I solved it.

Don't use the getClosest command as it returns a dictionary object despite the manual recommending this. I couldn't convert this dictionary object, specifically a key and a value within to a standalone object (vertex)

Instead use Instance.vertices.getByBoundingSphere(center=,radius=)
The center is basically a tuple of the coordinates and the radius is the tolerance. This returns an array of vertices

Answer (score 1):

If you want the geometrical object you just have to access the dictionary.
One way to do it is:

```
ForceVertex1 = hatInstance.vertices.getClosest(coordinates=((x,y,z,))[0][0]
```

This will return the vertices object only, which you can assign to a set or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Found a solution to actually address the original question:

```py
    part=mdb.models[modelName].parts[partName]
    v=part.vertices.getClosest(coordinates=(((x,y,z)),))
```

Note the formatting requirement for coordinates ((( )),), three sets of parenthesis with a comma. This will find the vertex closest to the specified point. In order to use this to create a set, I found you need to massage the Abaqus Python interface to return the vertex in a format that uses their "getSequenceFromMask" method. In order to create a set, the edges, faces, and/or vertices need to be of type "Sequence", which is internal to Abaqus.  To do this, I then use the following code:

```py
    v2=part.verticies.findAt((((v[0][1])),))
    part.Set(name='setName', vertices=v2)
```

Note, v[0][1] will give you the point at which the vertex lies on. Note again the format of the specified point using the findAt method (((point)),)  with three sets of parenthesis and a comma. This will return a vertex that uses the getSequenceFromMask method in Abaqus (you can check by typing v2 then enter in the python box at the bottom of CAE, works with Abaqus 2020). This is type "Sequence" (you can check by typing type(V2)) and this can be used to create a set. If you do not format the point in findAt correctly (e.g., findAt(v[0][1]), without the parenthesis and comma), it will return an identical vertex as you get by accessing the dictionary returned using getClosest (e.g., v[0][0]). This is type 'Vertex' and cannot be used to create a set, even though it asks for a vertex. If you know the exact point where the vertex is, then you do not need the first step. You can simply use the findAt method with the correct formatting. However, the tolerance for findAt is very small (1e-6) and will return an empty sequence if nothing is found within the tolerance. If you only have a ballpark idea of where the vertex is located, then you need to use the getClosest method first. This indeed gets the closest vertex to the specified point, which may or may not be the one you are interested in.

Original post:

None of these answers work for a similar problem I am having while trying to create a set of faces within some range near a point. If I use getClosest as follows

```
    f=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].faces.getClosest(coordinates=((0,0,0),), searchTolerance=1)
    mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].Set(faces=f, name='faceSet')
```

I get an error "TypeError: Keyword error on faces".
If I access the dictionary via face=f[0], I get error "Feature Creation Failed". If I access the tuple within the dictionary via f[0][0], I get the error "TypeError: keyword error on faces" again.

The option to use .getByBoundingSphere doesn't work either, because the faces in my model are massive, and the faces have to be completely contained within the sphere for Abaqus to "get" them, basically requiring me to create a sphere that encompasses the entire model.

My solution was to create my own script as follows:

```
    import numpy as np
    model=mdb.models['Model-1']
    part=model.parts['Part-1']
    faceSave=[]
    faceSave2=[]
    x=np.arange(-1,1,0.1)
    y=np.arange(-1,1,0.1)
    z=np.arange(-1,1,0.1)
    for x1 in x:
        for y1 in y:
            for z1 in z:
                f=part.faces.findAt(((x1,y1,z1),))
                if len(f)>0:
                    if f[0] in faceSave2:
                        None
                    else:
                        faceSave.append(f)
                        faceSave2.append(f[0])
    part.Set(faces=faceSave,name='faceSet')
```

This works, but it's extraordinarily slow, in part because "findAt" will throw a warning to the console whenever it doesn't find a face, and it usually doesn't find a face with this approach. The code above basically looks within a small cube for any faces, and puts them in the list "faceSave". faceSave2 is setup to ensure that duplicate faces aren't added to the list. Accessing the tuple (e.g, f[0] in the code above) contains the unique information about the face, whereas 'f' is just a pointer to the 'findAt' command. Strangely, you can use the pointer 'f' to create a Set, but you cannot use the actual face object 'f[0]' to create a set. The problem with this approach for general use is, the tolerance for "findAt" is super small, so, you either have to be confident where things are located in your model, or have the step size be 1e-6 in np.arange() to ensure you don't miss a face that's in the cube. With a tiny step size, expect the code to take forever.

At any rate, I can use a tuple (or a list of tuples) obtained via "findAt" to create a Set in Abaqus. However, I cannot use the tuple obtained via "getClosest" to make a set, even though I see no difference between the two objects. It's unfortunate, because getClosest gives me the exact info I need effectively immediately without my jumbled mess of for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

@anarchoNobody:
Thank you so much for your edited answer!
This workaround works great, also with faces. I spent a lot of hours trying to figure out why .getClosest does not provide a working result for creating a set, but with the workaround and the number of brackets it works.
If applied with several faces, the code has to be slightly modified:

````
    faces=((mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['TT-1'].faces.getClosest(
        coordinates=(((10.0, 10.0, 10.0)),), searchTolerance=2)),
        (mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['TT-1'].faces.getClosest(
        coordinates=((-10.0, 10.0, 10.0),), searchTolerance=2)),)
    faces1=(mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['Tube-1'].faces.findAt((((
        faces[0][0][1])),)),
        mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['Tube-1'].faces.findAt((((
        faces[1][0][1])),)),)
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Surface(name='TT-inner-surf', side1Faces=faces1)
```
````